# Kendo Chart : Order of drawing for the series?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I am having kendo chart with two series. The first one is a `scatterLine` series and the second one is a simple `scatter` series with visible markers. Currently the second series is drawn first and the markers appear bellow the points from the `scatterLine` series, which makes them hard to see. I tried changing the order of the series, when they are defined, but this did not helped me. So folks, do you know how I can tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are correct about kendo drawing the line on top.

I guess your best bet is to use shape, background, line thickness, color, and opacity to get the look you want.

> **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/UgeLU)**

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
    legend: {
        position: "right"
    },
    series: [{
        name: "January 2010",
        type: "scatterLine",
        color: "rgba(245,150,44,0.85)",
        markers: {
            background: "rgba(255,255,255,0.1)",
          type: "triangle",
          border: {
            width: 1.2
          }
        },
        data: [
        [21.7, 3], [13.6, 3.5], [13.6, 3], [29.9, 3], [21.7, 20], [19, 2], [10.9, 3], [28, 4], [27.1, 0.3], [16.4, 4], [13.6, 0], [19, 5], [16.4, 3], [24.5, 3], [32.6, 3], [27.1, 4], [13.6, 6], [13.6, 8], [13.6, 5], [10.9, 4], [16.4, 0], [32.6, 10.3], [21.7, 20.8], [24.5, 0.8], [16.4, 0], [21.7, 6.9], [13.6, 7.7], [16.4, 0], [8.1, 0], [16.4, 0], [16.4, 0]]
    },{
        name: "January 2008",
        type: "scatter",
        color: "rgba(59,96,27, 0.9)",
        markers: {
            background: "rgba(59,96,27, 0.3)",
          border: {
            width: 2
          }
        },                    data: [
        [16.4, 5.4], [21.7, 2], [25.4, 3], [19, 2], [10.9, 1], [13.6, 3.2], [10.9, 7.4], [10.9, 0], [10.9, 8.2], [16.4, 0], [16.4, 1.8], [13.6, 0.3], [13.6, 0], [29.9, 0], [27.1, 2.3], [16.4, 0], [13.6, 3.7], [10.9, 5.2], [16.4, 6.5], [10.9, 0], [24.5, 7.1], [10.9, 0], [8.1, 4.7], [19, 0], [21.7, 1.8], [27.1, 0], [24.5, 0], [27.1, 0], [29.9, 1.5], [27.1, 0.8], [22.1, 2]]
    }],
    xAxis: {
        max: 35,
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: -5,
        max: 25,
    }
});
```

Comment: do you think that there is a way to hide the line connecting the markers if I switch the scatter chart to scatterLine?

Comment: @Wosh, yes, give the series color a zero opacity. See updated demo: http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/UgeLU